# What is the difference between Ubuntu Phone and Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Several days ago, Ubuntu 13.10 was released for Desktops, Servers, Phones, etc. On the Ubuntu website, Ubuntu for Phones is listed as officially available for the GSM Galaxy Nexus (codenames `takju` and `yakju`) and the Nexus 4.

The main installation process is for Linux only. If you scroll down the site you will find under the section "Further Information" a link to -> "Manual download and installation instructions".

If you follow the link you will be redirected to the [Ubuntu Wiki page for for Ubuntu Touch](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install).
 Here there is a list of supported devices, which in addition to the above mentioned devices, includes the Nexus 7 2012 and Nexus 10.

So I am looking for `.img` files that I can flash with `fastboot`. On the wiki site there is a section called "Manual Download & Installation" which contains [a link to a download site](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/current/) where there are `.img` and `.zip` files. These files are for13.10 and where updated 17-Oct-2013.

So, what is the difference between Ubuntu for Phones and Ubuntu Touch, and why does the official Ubuntu website not have installation instructions `.img` files that could be used with `fastboo` on Windows? I can set up a Ubuntu VM, but many people can't.

Answer (score 2):

This is a community website, "we" did nothing, but Canonical...

Ubuntu Phone is used as term for describing a Smartphone with Ubuntu Touch installed. Ubuntu Touch is a User Interface for Ubuntu, that can be run on smartphones. You need an ubuntu system (on PC) to install ubuntu touch on your smartphone.

Ubuntu Touch is not intended to be installed by people who are not tech savy, by now.

Install instructions can be found here: [Ubuntu Touch Installation Instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install)